# Insert variable value into cell with text VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert the number contained by the variable Row4Num -1 into the Active Cell, along with some text, but I can't quite figure out the syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated-- Thanks!

```
      Range("I7").Value = "=""Teams:  & "" Row4Num - 1"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
Range("I7").Value = "Teams:  " & Row4Num - 1
```

When using VBA variables in a String they must be outside the `""` and concatenated with &.  Everything inside the quotes will be treated as a text string.

Comment: @reggie86 glad to help.  Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.